# How to add a multi-emitter BJT to LTSpice?

Tags: bjt, simulation, spice, ltspice

I want to simulate the standard TTL NAND gate which contains a multi-emitter BJT transistor in LTSpice. I've searched the components available in LTSpice but didn't found this component. How can I add it to LTSpice (if possible)?

Answer (score 3):

I have done this for analog ASIC design. You use 2 ( or more) transistors with base and collectors in parallel and separate emitters. To make the schematic look correct I made a sub block with a 2 emitter transistor symbol.